# React bubbling up not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-dom

I have a child component and a parent component and I am trying to bubble up some data from the child to the parent like so

Child:

```
bubbleUp(data){
  alert(data);
  this.props.addToLib(data);
}
...
render() {
  let formattedDate = this.props.releaseDate;
  return (
    <div className="component-search-result-row" onClick={() => {this.bubbleUp(this.props)}}
```

Parent:

```
addToLib(data){
    alert(data);
    this.setState({selectedData : data});
}
...
    render(){
    return(
    <SearchResultRow addToLib={() => this.addToLib()}/>
    )};
```

Now I am getting data from the first alert(the child) but I am getting undefined from the parent. Any idea of what I am missing?

Comment: Your callback has no parameters. Instead of `() => this.addToLib()`, do `(data) => this.addToLib(data)`. `this.addToLib` would work too, but only if you don't need `this` to be bound to the component

Comment: thanks, feel real smart about this question now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your render method for your parent:

```
render(){
    return(
    <SearchResultRow addToLib={() => this.addToLib()}/>
)};
```

Your method does not take in any data, but instead calls `this.addToLib()` without any arguments.

If you change it to this: it should work: (note the extra `data`)

```
render(){
    return(
    <SearchResultRow addToLib={(data) => this.addToLib(data)}/>
)};
```